# Do the zeros of a prime ideal on closed points of the Zariski topology uniquely determine it?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

That is, if two prime ideals share the exact same zeros on maximal ideals, are they the same ideal?  Or at least is there a result with other assumptions that shows this?

Learning algebraic geometry at the moment and not that deep into it, but this keeps popping into my mind as I read.  It seems like it should be true (at least for nice conditions like Noetherian rings), but I'm struggling to see a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Hoot's excellent answer, a ring $R$ is called Jacobson if every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$ is equal to the intersection of the maximal ideals in $V(\mathfrak{p})$. It follows immediately that if $R$ is a Jacobson ring and $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}\in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ satisfy $V(\mathfrak{p})\cap\mathrm{mSpec}(R)=V(\mathfrak{q})\cap\mathrm{mSpec}(R)$, then $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{q}$.

One (general) version of the Nullstellensatz says that if $R$ is a Jacobson ring and $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra, then $S$ is Jacobson as well. Examples of Jacobson rings include $\mathbf{Z}$ and any field. So finitely generated algebras over either of these rings will have the property you ask about.

This will not be true in general for non-Jacobson rings. For example, if $R$ is a local ring with at least two distinct prime ideals, then $R$ will not be Jacobson and it will not have the property you want. Indeed, for such a ring, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime different from the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then $V(\mathfrak{p})\cap\mathrm{mSpec}(R)=V(\mathfrak{p})\cap\{\mathfrak{m}\}=\{\mathfrak{m}\}=V(\mathfrak{m})$.

Comment: Nice remark on local rings being non-Jacobson!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the question is whether $V(\mathfrak{p})$ and $V(\mathfrak{q})$ having the same closed points would imply $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{q}$. As you suspect, it's not true in general: if $A$ is a local ring then you can't distinguish any prime ideals in this way.

On the other hand, if $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over a field then closed points are dense as a consequence of the Nullstellensatz (great exercise!), and I think you should be able to use that to verify your conjecture in that case.